# ¿Cómo retornar Null en constructor de clase?

Tags: c++, gtk

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Gtkmm y estoy compilando en tiempo de ejecución una Interfaz de Usuario realizada en Glade.

El asunto es que estoy compilandolo en el constructor de la clase, como es en tiempo de ejecución, puede surgir algún inconveniente en la compilación y darme una excepción, esta compilación es crucial, si no resulta no se monta la interfaz y la clase no es instanciada correctamente.

Por buenas practicas, no quiero tener que regresar una excepción en un constructor, deseo que el constructor o retorne la memoria dada o un `nullptr`.

Mi constructor es el siguiente:

```
FeAFeSinTiempo::FeAFeSinTiempo()
{
    bool intancia = false;

    try
    {
        //Compilación en tiempo de ejecución
        _refGridContenedorPrincipal = Gtk::Builder::create_from_string(_interfazGlade);

        intancia = true;
    }
    catch(const Gtk::BuilderError &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    if(intancia)
    {            
        //Aquí instancio los otros objetos de clase
    }
    else        
    {
        this = nullptr; //<== esto no es correcto
    }


}//Constructor por defecto
```

Lo que deseo es que si no se logra la compilación en tiempo de ejecución por alguna razón, detener la asignación de memoria para ese objeto y me retorne un `nullptr`.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera para hacerlo?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al grano: **no puedes**.

En primer lugar, los constructores **no pueden devolver nada**. Su misión en inicializar un bloque de memoria a un estado conocido, pero dicho bloque **ha de estar disponible antes de la ejecución del código del constructor**.

Incluso una llamada a `new` se descompone en 2 pasos: **reserva** de la memoria e **invocación del constructor**. Pero siempre, **siempre**, la memoria ha de estar disponible en primer lugar. Por lo tanto, ni siquiera usando `new` podrás conseguir lo que pretendes:

```
FeAFeSinTiempo *ptr = nullptr;

try {
  ptr = new FeAFeSinTiempo( );
} catch( ... ) {
  // Ignoramos las excepciones.
}

std::cout << reinterpret_cast< void * >( ptr ) << '\n';
```

> 0x556bbb71e005

**Siempre** se mostrará una dirección distinta de `nullptr`, independientemente de que el constructor lance o no excepciones (excepto si tenemos una excepción `bad_alloc`, pero esa se lanza en errores de reserva de memoria, antes de llamar al constructor).

Si podrías, por otra parte, modificar un puntero en el bloque `catch( )`:

```
FeAFeSinTiempo *ptr = nullptr;

try {
  ptr = new FeAFeSinTiempo( );
} catch( const std::bad_alloc & ) {
  // Aquí no hacemos nada.
} catch( ... ) {
  delete ptr;
  ptr = nullptr;
}

std::cout << reinterpret_cast< void * >( ptr ) << '\n';
```

> 0x000000000000

De todas formas, tu planteamiento no es correcto. Si se produce una excepción, el código a continuación no se ejecuta, por lo que no es necesario que realices mas comprobaciones en ese nivel, aunque si en un nivel superior:

```
class FeAFeSinTiempo {
public:
  FeAFeSinTiempo::FeAFeSinTiempo( ) {
    try {
      //Compilación en tiempo de ejecución
      _refGridContenedorPrincipal = Gtk::Builder::create_from_string( _interfazGlade );
    }

    //Aquí instancio los otros objetos de clase
  }

  ...

};

int main( ) {
  try {
    FeAFeSinTiempo feafe;

    feafe.doIt( );
  } catch( const std::bad_alloc & ) {
    std::cerr << "Sin memoria :-(\n";
  } catch( const Gtk::BuilderError &ex ) {
      std::cerr << "Metedura de pata mia :-(\n" << ex.what( ) << '\n';
  } catch( ... ) {
    std::cerr << "Error totalmente inesperado :-O\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Lo que si tienes que asegurarte es de dejar tu instancia en un estado consistente aunque se produzcan excepciones en el constructor; y luego realizar las operaciones pertinentes en el destructor.